# Fibonacci Sequence using Cache

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to make use of a cache to improve the performance of my Fibonacci method. However, it is still taking a lot of time to compute even fibonacci(40).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FibWithCache {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter Fibonacci index: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        System.out.println(fibonacci(index));
    }

    private static long fibonacci(int index) {

        long result = 0;
        long[] fibCache = new long[200];

        if(index==0)
            return 0;
        else if(index == 1)
            return 1;
        else if(fibCache[index] != 0)
            return fibCache[index];
        else {
            result = fibonacci(index-1) + fibonacci(index-2);
            fibCache[index] = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I unable to benefit from the cache?

Answer (score 12):

Hint: The issue is that each recursive call to `fibonacci()` has its own cache. For every call you create an empty cache, store something in it, and immediately discard it.

What you want is one cache shared by all the calls.

I'll let you figure out how best to do it. :)

Comment: I declared the array in the class and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

There should only be one instance to `fibCache` (it has to be `static`).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FibonacciCache {

    private int[] cache = new int[1000];
    
    public FibonacciCache(){
        // n de 1 = 1;
        cache[1] = 1;
    }

    public int fibonacciDe(int n){
        if(cache[n] != 0){
            return cache[n];
        }
    
        // n de 0 = 0
        if(n <= 0){
            return 0;
        }
                        
        int result = fibonacciDe(n-1) + fibonacciDe(n-2);
        cache[n] = result;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why and how this code can reply to the question ?